# Laravel Eloquent Catch Special Expection

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, exception, eloquent

I'm currently trying the following: In my db, I have a column called `templateURL`, which is a unique key, so it may only exist once. Then if something tries to submit a form, where this is the same as already exist an error is thrown, saying 
`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'templateURL'`.

Of course it does, that's why I made the column unique. But: What I want is not the default Laravel Error, but getting back to the form with the values still entered and a message (alert from bootstrap for example or just a div next to the input field) saying that this already exist and asking to chooose another one. So I need to catch this exception and do something custom instead. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: read this https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-form-validation

Comment: @shoieb0101 you mean the thing with `$rules`? Looks good, but can I also put this in my Controller of I have to put it in my route like he did?

Comment: you can put your validation rules into your controller or use formRequest for validation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Thanks, this works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to wrap your database operation into a `try-catch` block and catch the error and do something else when you get a error, maybe redirect with old input data with a error message.

The error code for [duplicate entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry) is **1062**. So if you get 1062 as error code that means this data is a duplicate entry. Here is the code look like for catching this exception.

```
try {

    $data = Model::create(array(
      'templateURL' => 'some value ',
    ));

} catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
    if($errorCode == 1062){
      // we have a duplicate entry problem
    }
}
```

Or if you wish not to handle the exception yourself, you can take help of Laravel Validator. Like following in your controller

```
// validation rules
$rules = array(
    'templateURL'            => 'unique:YourTableNameHere'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// check if the validation failed
if ($validator->fails()) {

    // get the error messages from the validator
    $messages = $validator->messages();

    // redirect user back to the form with the errors from the validator
    return Redirect::to('form')
        ->withErrors($validator);

} else {

    // validation successful

    $data = Model::create(array(
      'templateURL' => 'some value ',
    ));
}
```

Then in your view template you can access the error messages via `$errors` variable.
Learn more about validation there https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: First thanks for the answer. but something seems to be wrong, I just tried to `echo "test"` in the catch for errorCode 1062, but there is no `test` echoed, instead I still get the laravel error. Also, I'm wondering how I (if there's errorCode 1062) can get back to the page with values still entered and show the message that this already exists

Comment: 1062 error code is for mysql? Are you using mysql? would you try redirect instead of echo "test"?

Comment: I'm using eloquent, so it's a mysql db but I'm not using it directly, but the error message says 1062 as well. But the comment for my answer looks good and easy as well and I directly get back to the form etc.

Comment: Updated the answer with Laravel Validator example.